# Emptying HTML tags with sed

Tags: html, sed

I want to empty the content of every HTML tag but *"keeping the structure"*.

From:

```html
<h5>Holdrs <div class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Accounts with ..."></div></h5>
<div class="value">
  <span class="amount">25,241</span><a class="smallnav" href="/c/token/0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B7"><svg class="icon-s icon">
```

I want to get:

```
<>Holdrs <><><>
<>
  <>25,241<><><>
```

From my understanding of sed this should be:

```
sed 's/<.*>/<>/'
```

but it only returns:

```
<>
<>
  <>
```

(Tested here: https://sed.js.org/?gist=7af9c1c1762a6a93d582502b3d4fe22f).

What I'm doing wrong? What's the correct pattern?

Comment: Note that attempting to manipulate HTML with regular expressions usually ends badly. At some point you'll have a `<` or `>` in an attribute, a `>` in the text, or some other thing you hadn't thought of. The right way to manipulate HTML is to use an HTML parser which can keep track of the context and interpret things correctly.

Comment: [Relevant cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/525036).
Note that this looks very mutch like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167668).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`*` is greedy, so `<.*>` matches everything from the first `<` to the last `>` in the line. Some tools understand `*?` as non-greedy analogue of `*`, [but not `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297686/108618).

In your case one can still go with `sed`. Replace `.` (any character) with `[^>]` (any character but `>`). You should also add `g` flag because you want to replace all matches in the line, not just the first.

This should work:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>/<>/g'
```

Comment: Note: this won't work if there's any `<` or `>` in f.e. HTML attributes or in HTML nodes (like in JavaScript snippets).

Comment: I think this will also break on multiline tags: `<tag value="line1\nline2"/>`

Comment: Don't forget commented-out tags that sed doesn't understand as being commented-out.  http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Comment: Or `<![CDATA[]]>`. _Generating_ XML is fairly simple, parsing less so.

Answer (score 9):

Just rename all nodes to empty strings and delete all attributes using [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt):

```
xml ed -r '//*' '' -d '//@*'
```

This will add an XML header (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`) and leave a slash in the closing tags (`</>`) which may be acceptable, or which you can remove with an additional `tail`/`sed` pass.

Like others have already said, `sed` alone will never be able to handle all cases correctly.

Comment: If you're going to do a simple sed-pass afterwards, using empty tags isn't even necessary. You can use `<Foo></Foo>` explicitly. The goal is to get rid of the regex wildcard; `<Foo>` is a simple literal match.

Comment: @MSalters Wouldn't that  still fall prey to the problems like CDATA and <script> tags that motivated us to avoid regexen in the first place?

Comment: @DanielWagner: It starts out by reducing the impact, since the `<!` prefix already cannot match `<Foo>`. Still, the CDATA can _contain_ <Foo>, which is a second problem. But the idea is that <> is more likely to occur than <Foo>. And furthermore, Foo is here  the usual meta-variable. You can use a locally generated GUID instead, which due  to the usual GUID properties will statistically not occur in your input text.

Comment: @DanielWagner Also, the OP didn't explain what purpose those empty tags `<>` serve. Depending on how the output is used, `</>`  or `<Foo>`/`</Foo>` can actually be acceptable as is.

Comment: @MSalters Nice, I love the idea of putting randomness in the place of `Foo`!